# Sublimelinter is unresponsive, lint is installed, user settings correct, path is correct

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, jslint, jshint

I have Sublime Text 3, with Sublimelinter, the sublimelinter-jshint package, and jshint installed with the correct path set. I can run 'jslint app.js' in the terminal and it runs fine. Mac OSX.

```
{
    "user": {
        "debug": true,
        "delay": 0.25,
        "error_color": "D02000",
        "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Default/Default.gutter-theme",
        "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
        "lint_mode": "background",
        "linters": {
            "coffeelint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": []
            },
            "csslint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "errors": "",
                "excludes": [],
                "ignore": "",
                "warnings": ""
            },
            "jshint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": [],
                "note": true
            }
        },
        "mark_style": "solid underline",
        "no_column_highlights_line": false,
        "passive_warnings": false,
        "paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [
                //"/usr/local/bin/jshint" i've tried this too
            ],
            "windows": []
        },
        "python_paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "rc_search_limit": 3,
        "shell_timeout": 10,
        "show_errors_on_save": true,
        "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
        "syntax_map": {
            "html (django)": "html",
            "html (rails)": "html",
            "html 5": "html",
            "php": "html",
            "python django": "python"
        },
        "warning_color": "DDB700",
        "wrap_find": true
    }
}
```

No errors are being output from the console when I run commands to the package. if I run 'show all errors' it says 'No errors found'.

Comment: Fwiw, there should be another file with the prefs for the linter. I only have ST2 handy, but there it's in `Preferences >>> Package Settings >>> JSLint >>> Settings-Default`. Really quickly, it looks like you're using JS*Hint*, not JS*Lint*. I'm going to update your tag, just in case that's right. Which might explain things. Can you run `jshint app.js` (comment says yes?)? Also, I think the plugin uses node to run things... In which case you want to see if you can use `node jshint app.js`. (Could be mistaking it with another plugin) Maybe just tell us exactly what steps you used to install.

Comment: [Fwiw](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/troubleshooting.html?highlight=node): `Another possibility is that an executable called by the linter executable is missing. For example, if jshint is available but node is not, you would see something like this in the console:

SublimeLinter: jshint output:
env: node: No such file or directory`

Comment: But if you're seeing nothing, maybe it's also worth showing us what's in your package pref file and what's in `app.js`.